# a pass through query to translate the data type from bigint to int

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to “fool” an odbc connection (SQL to Access 2013) into not displaying my bigint data as #deleted….
I need to create a pass through query to translate the data type from bigint to int.
Would anyone know where to start? Or perhaps point me in the right direction. Been searching for a few days and haven't had any luck so far.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whatever database engine you have probably has a cast function.  However, if the value is too big to be an integer, you need a better plan.

Comment: In general such columns are returned as a string - and in most cases that's not a problem. So a linked table should not display deleted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Access, and exactly why Microsoft [implemented BigInt support](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2017/03/06/new-in-access-2016-large-number-bigint-support/) in later versions of Access 2016.

You can't work around it on the client side, aside from updating your Access version. You can use casting versions on the server side to try to avoid the issue (e.g. `Cast(MyBigInt As Float) As MyFloat` for T-SQL). Note that you will have to use appropriate data type and size for the values you're querying.